# c# Label "hitbox" - The Blank space counts as label, label is short

Tags: c#, label

there is my code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        games += 1;
        LocPoint += 1;
        Label label = new Label
        {

            Name = "game_" + games,
            Text = "New Game",
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
            Location = new Point(25, LocPoint * 24)
        };
        Controls.Add(label);
        label.Click += Label_Click;
```

And there is what ive got [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IpQY.png)

But as you can see the Cursor is in part where the label text isnt.
and its max of 16characters ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not set to any other value Label property Height is set to 23 and Width to 100.
Set them to a default different value or try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    games += 1;
    LocPoint += 1;
    Label label = new Label
    {

        Name = "game_" + games,
        Text = "New Game",
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
        Location = new Point(25, LocPoint * 24),
        AutoSize = true
    };
    Controls.Add(label);
    label.Click += Label_Click;
```

AutoSize will set the value of Height and Width to minimum size depending on the size of text.